# android add filename to bytestream

Tags: android

im trying to send a file in android through sockets. i want to add the filename with the bytestream and then send it to the server. how do i do that? and then how do i seperate the filename on the receiving side?
this is the code to send file :

```
 Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-1");
            File  f = new File(path);
            String filename=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            System.out.println("filename:"+filename); 
            fin.filename = "~"+filename;
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );

            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(f);
            Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-2");
            byte [] buffer  = new byte [(int)f.length()];
            System.out.println("SO sendFile f.length();" + f.length());
            int bytesRead =0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                System.out.println("SO sendFile" + bytesRead +filename);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            fileIn.close();
            Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-3");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your own protocol then you create a data packet that separate the two sections (filename and data). You need to denote clearly the separation via a particular boundary.

On the server, since you understand the protocol, the server will read back the whole data packet and it will separate the filename and data based on the given boundary.

[MIME data format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) use exactly this kind of data exchange and widely use with HTTP protocol. If you use the same MIME Data Format, another advantage is you could use  third party library to encode and decode your data such as [HttpMime](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/)

Below is the rough code to format the data using MIME data and send it through Socket

```
File  f = new File(path);
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
String filename=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

// create a multipart message
MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity();

// send the file inputstream as data
InputStreamBody isb = new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(f), "image/jpeg", filename);

// add key value pair. The key "imageFile" is arbitrary
multipartContent.addPart("imageFile", isb);

multipartContent.writeTo(out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Note that you would need [org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html) and [org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.InputStreamBody](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/InputStreamBody.html) from HttpMime project. On the server, you need MIME parser that would get back the filename and all the bytes content

To read the inputstream back on the server, you would need a class to parse the MIME message. You shouldn't have to write the parser yourself as MIME is a popular message format already unless you want to learn about the MIME message structure.

Below is the sample code using [MimeBodyPart](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/index.html?javax/mail/BodyPart.html) that is part of JavaMail.

```
MimeMultipart multiPartMessage = new MimeMultipart(new DataSource() {
    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        // this could be anything need be, this is just my test case and illustration
        return "image/jpeg";
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        // socket is the socket that you get from Socket.accept()
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        return inputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "socketDataSource";
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return socket.getOutputStream();
    }
});

// get the first body of the multipart message
BodyPart bodyPart = multiPartMessage.getBodyPart(0);

// get the filename back from the message
String filename = bodyPart.getFileName();

// get the inputstream back
InputStream bodyInputStream = bodyPart.getInputStream();

// do what you need to do here....
```

You could download JavaMail from [Oracle Website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138643.html) which also has dependency on [Java Activation Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-135046.html)

Comment: the file is sent using plain tcp/ip right so i dont know of any protocol..the code tells all what im doing..on the receiving side it simple gets the inputstream and passes it to the receiveFile method..please tell me how to use the httpmime lib if thats the solution. thanks.

Comment: @hardy I'll try to write up a simple pseudocode illustrating the idea on Android side. What language the server is written on as I might not have enough familiarity with it to provide pseudocode. Even if I don't, I might be able to help you to find a library that parse MIME message for the server.

Comment: thank you. its a client server thing. so the server shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: I've added the code for the client to send the file along with the filename. When you say "client-server" thing, you are saying basically the server is also written in Android Phone?

Comment: yes. i do have a server for authentication that runs on php but that has nothing to do with the socket communication. the clients communicate using the sockets, the server is also implemented in android.

Comment: thank you so so much :) i shall get back to you once i test this..and if i cant figure out what to do on receiveFile then i shall ask u for help again :)

Comment: Sure thing. Let me try to cook up an example on reading as well and I'll put it up as part of an answer

Comment: I've added the code that read the MIME Message that you could use on the server side. It uses the classes from JavaMail project.