# Transfer a file between Android devices?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, serversocket

I'm making a code and I want to send a mp4 file to another Android device. I have reached to connect both Androids via Wifi and write from one a simple for cycle from 1-20 and the other Android device reads and displays the number that is sent.

Here it is the interesting part of the "sender":

```
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port);
                connected = true;
                while (connected) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                    .getOutputStream())), true);


                        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {


                            out.println(i);

                            i=i++;
```

and the "receiver":

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);

                        // listen for incoming clients
                        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()),8*1024);
```

This works great! But I want to send a file from one device to another instead of an int. How can I make this?????

Answer (score 1):

You need to package the data to the stream through a some kind of data format. One way to do this is to use the common MIME data format which is commonly used to send attachment in email.

I have answered other question related to sending binary via socket using this format in [the following SO Question - android add filename to bytestream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374481/android-add-filename-to-bytestream/7374554#7374554). You could check the accepted answer for that question.

For your reference, I just copied the code for sending and receiving through socket from that question below.

```
File  f = new File(path);
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
String filename=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

// create a multipart message
MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity();

// send the file inputstream as data
InputStreamBody isb = new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(f), "image/jpeg", filename);

// add key value pair. The key "imageFile" is arbitrary
multipartContent.addPart("imageFile", isb);

multipartContent.writeTo(out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

And the code to read it back below using [MimeBodyPart](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/index.html?javax/mail/BodyPart.html) that is part of JavaMail.

```
MimeMultipart multiPartMessage = new MimeMultipart(new DataSource() {
    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        // this could be anything need be, this is just my test case and illustration
        return "image/jpeg";
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        // socket is the socket that you get from Socket.accept()
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        return inputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "socketDataSource";
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return socket.getOutputStream();
    }
});

// get the first body of the multipart message
BodyPart bodyPart = multiPartMessage.getBodyPart(0);

// get the filename back from the message
String filename = bodyPart.getFileName();

// get the inputstream back
InputStream bodyInputStream = bodyPart.getInputStream();

// do what you need to do here....
```

Comment: Nice!! So I will ignore the part of the filename.

What is for the "multipartContent.addPart("imageFile", isb);
"???

And how can I get the file in another Android phone?? Cause the answer you especified is for the JavaMail??

Thanks!!

Comment: JavaMail is just used since it contains the library for the MIME Format (MimeMultipart), but it has nothing to do with the mail. The filename is basically the metadata for the filename that you transfer to the other side (if it doesn't matter, you could put anything), and "imageFile" is just the key for the data, you could name it anything. It was only there as a sample. I use the same pattern if I need to transfer binary in my projects as this is proven to work in email attachment. It's easier than devising my own data format

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source project **released by Google** you can take a look at it and have a general idea about connecting devices and sharing files between them.

Here is the link: [android-fileshare](http://code.google.com/p/android-fileshare/)